# How to prevent Timer thread from deleting the item while that item might possibly be used in another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am writing software for RFID tags and facing concurrency issue.

In my software, tags have user defined "lifetime" measured in minutes. Once tag is read, it is place in `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tripple> SeenEnoughDict` (string is tag's ID, and `Tripple` is `struct` that keeps `System.Threading.Timer` and couple of the things such has how many times the tag was seen). Reason behind having a `Timer`, so that tags would not clog down the `SeenEnoughDict`. `Timer` schedules tags to be deleted from `SeenEnoughDict` when it's lifetime is over.

```
Parallel.ForEach(_myReaderTC.Cast<Tag>(), t => // _myReaderTC is tag collection that   
                                               //comes back from hardware.
    {
        Tripple temp_tripple;
        // is it in dict ?
        if (SeenEnoughDict.TryGetValue(t.ID, out temp_tripple))
        {
            // Antenna different from prev read ?
            if (temp_tripple.prev_antenna != t.Antenna)
            {
                temp_tripple.prev_antenna = t.Antenna;
                temp_tripple.num_of_times_seen = 1;
                return;
            }
            // antennas are the same, was it seen enough times on particular antenna ?
            if (temp_tripple.num_of_times_seen == _myCaptRespConf.valid_reads)
            {
                // Remove tag id from the dictionary, and delete it's timer
                Tripple temp;
                SeenEnoughDict.TryRemove(t.ID, out temp);
                temp.timer.Dispose();
            }
                // have not seen it enough times 
            else
            {
                temp_tripple.num_of_times_seen++;
                return; 
            }
        }
            // not in the dict 
        else
        {  
            // add the tag's id to the dict and schedule it for deletion
            SeenEnoughDict.TryAdd(t.ID,
                new Tripple(t.Antenna,
                    new Timer(
                              // lamda; schedule tags for deletion
                              (Object tagID) => { 
                                                    Tripple temp;
                                                    // from temp dict 
                                                    SeenEnoughDict.TryRemove((string)tagID, out temp);
                                                    temp.timer.Dispose(); 
                                                },
                              t.ID, // parameter to lambda
                              // _myCaptRespConf.TagPersistence is tags lifecycle time in minutes
                              new TimeSpan(0, 0, _myCaptRespConf.TagPersistence, 0, 0),
                              new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, -1))));
            return;
        }
    }
```

If you look at my code, it is very possible to get a race: while one thread is going through the `if (SeenEnoughDict.TryGetValue(t.ID, out temp_tripple)) {....}`, and the second thread (`Timer`) kicks in and deletes the item from dictionary.

How should I properly lock the item in the dictionary?

Comment: Does it matter? The race condition is resolved by doing something to guarantee one or the other thread wins. But do you really care? If the timer wins, that's no different than you coming along hours later and finding the tag not in the dictionary. Similarly, if recent process of a tag were in some way intended to suppress or delay the timer-based deletion, you would have code there to do that, but you don't (and if you did, that would automatically reset the timer if processing the tag occurred before the timer expired). What is the actual problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the item in hand (returned by TryGetValue) another thread might remove it from the dictionary but that doesn't cause the actual object to be destroyed, since you have a reference to it.

Comment: Interesting, I was thinking in terms of C++ - delete the items, invalidates any pointers to that item. 
In .NET it not true.

Comment: @newprint There is no `delete` in .Net, deallocating memory is the job of the garbage collector. Think of it this way: if you have `std::map<std::string, Tripple*>` and call `erase()`, it also won't deallocate the `Tripple` object.